# How To Remove background color In Wordpress Footer

Tags: css, wordpress, html, twitter-bootstrap

While Converting this theme On My own from my html page to wordpress... I almost have everything working but for some reason I cannot get rid of this white background in my footer. Ive tried everything and I cant figure it out. Im new to this wordpress thing Ive looked around for hours trying to figure it out, Still Got nothing
 [ScreenShot Of My WebSite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV1jp.png)
Heres the code in my Footer.php file in my custom wordpress theme. have a look at it yourself 
http://wp.trillumonopoly.com

```
<footer>

                                <br>
                                <div class="container"  style="border-radius:5px; border-color:black; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.6)">
                                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"><h2><font color="White">Twitter</font></h2><BR>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"><h2><font color="White">Facebook</font></h2><BR>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"><h2><font color="White">ACCOUNT</font></h2><BR><BR> </div>

                                    </div><br>
                                </div>




            </div>




<center>
<p><?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'Footer')); ?></font></p>
<!-- copyright --><br><br>

                <font size=".5em"><p class="copyright">

                    &copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> Copyright <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>. <?php _e('Powered by Forever Digi Empire LLC'); ?>

                    </center>
                </font>
                <!-- /copyright -->


</footer>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/nav.js"></script>



<script language=JavaScript>

<!--





var message="Thats Property iLLumonopoly Global Publishing. Unauthorized Duplication is prohibited";

///////////////////////////////////

function clickIE() {if (document.all) {(message);return false;}}

function clickNS(e) {if 

(document.layers||(document.getElementById&&!document.all)) {

if (e.which==2||e.which==3) {(message);return false;}}}

if (document.layers) 

{document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);document.onmousedown=clickNS;}

else{document.onmouseup=clickNS;document.oncontextmenu=clickIE;}



document.oncontextmenu=new Function("return false")

// --> 

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "f497004f-2790-48d8-888b-6fec35fdf757", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false});</script>

<script>

var options={ "publisher": "f497004f-2790-48d8-888b-6fec35fdf757", "position": "left", "ad": { "visible": false, "openDelay": 5, "closeDelay": 0}, "chicklets": { "items": ["facebook", "twitter", "googleplus", "myspace", "pinterest", "blogger", "email", "sharethis"]}};

var st_hover_widget = new sharethis.widgets.hoverbuttons(options);

</script> 

<script>

  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){

  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),

  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)

  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');



  ga('create', 'UA-72805834-1', 'auto');

  ga('send', 'pageview');



</script>





<script>

$('.menu_nav') .click (function () {
var href = $(this) .attr('href');
$('#contentarea').hide() .load(href).slideRight( 'very slow' )

    return false;
}); 
</script>

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `<font>` tag? The `<center>` tag? Is this 1996??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See 3rd line in your Code there is "background-color".....
Change the value of the background-color....
For example: background-color: #9C27B0; (color)

Your Modify 3rd line is:

```
<div class="container"  style="border-radius:5px; border-color:black; background-color: #9C27B0">
```

Answer (score 0):

I just changed your "footer" color in the Developer Tools on Chrome. NOTE: The div that resides within your footer DOES NOT fill the entire space of the footer. I would suggest to make another "wrapper" div that is defined in the space that the footer currently resides that spans the width and height to fill in that white space. OR you can probably add to the css file

```
footer{background-color:rgba(whatever, color, you, want);}
```